# Return current date when no date present in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I am using the below code to return data from a date column, but am unsure how to return today's date if no date present.

To put it in to context, a patient has a catheter inserted on a `date` and then removed on another `date`.  If it hasn't been removed (ie. there is no `date` in the "Removed" column), it is still present and so i need to replace `NULL` with the `current date`.

I get it to work where it just pulls back the current date for `NULL` and no other dates (for the patients who have entries in "`Removed`"),  and I can get the dates for the "`Removed`" with the rest as `NULL` easily enough, but cannot concatenate the two successfully.  My latest attempt is giving an incorrect param `count` error which I understand but not sure how to proceed.

```
select 
oid,
DATE_FORMAT(va.ins_dte, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Inserted',
(DATE_FORMAT(va.rem_dte, '%d/%m/%Y') , ifnull(va.rem_dte), curdate()) AS 'Removed'
from Vascular va
```

Can anyone tell me how to get all removed `dates` and where `NULL`, add the current `date` please?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of IFNULL is:

```
SELECT IFNULL (`NullableValue`, ValueIfNull)) FROM `TableName`
```

You should use it as the second parameter of `ifnull`:

```
ifnull(va.rem_dte, curdate())
```

Your final SQL should be like:

```
SELECT 
    oid, DATE_FORMAT(va.ins_dte, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Inserted',
    DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(va.rem_dte, CURDATE()), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Removed'
FROM Vascular va
```

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly!  I knew i was in the right park, just barking up the wrong tree!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, based on the documentation for [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT 
    oid,
    DATE_FORMAT(va.ins_dte, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Inserted',
    DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(va.rem_dte, CURDATE()), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Removed'
FROM Vascular va
```

For your case, you want to get the current date if `va.rem_dte` is `NULL`. This can be expressed as

```
IFNULL(va.rem_dte, CURDATE())
```

The result of that expression can then be passed to the `DATE_FORMAT` function:

```
DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(va.rem_dte, CURDATE()), '%d/%m/%Y')
```